# Node - Set virtual host on local computer

Tags: node.js, express, virtualhost

I'm trying to set virtual host on my local machine for my Node (Express) project. But I cant figure out how to avoid port number

This is what I had entered on my /etc/hosts file.

```
192.168.151.207  www.potato.com
192.168.151.207  www.tomato.com
```

I can access site by www.potato.com:3000 but I want it to be simply www.potato.com.

I was Googling for last few days but all most all the solution says to use Nginx for reverse proxy. I also read somewhere that if I use Nginx I can't use Socket. And socket is something which I have to use in next phase of the project.

Any help is heartily appreciated.

Comment: You need a reverse proxy to do that.

Comment: Do you mean no options are available if I want to do it solely by node?

Comment: You can use `webpack-dev-server` to set up the proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the answer to my question. I use Nginx only and setup a reverse proxy. 
First on my /etc/hosts file I add the domain which I want to use.

> 127.0.0.1       tomato.com

This means whenever I open this URL "tomato.com" browser will change for 127.0.0.1. But my Express server is running on 127.0.0.1:3000. Now we need to point 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1:3000. Using Nginx we can configure this. Below given line of code does this. /etc/nginx/sites-available/tomato.conf

```html
server_name tomato.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"

}
```

For more detail check this post from [Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [virtualhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtualhost) npm package?

> Make your HTTP server hostname-aware very simply.
>
> You define the handler for each server name, and that will return the
>   final handler to be passed to your HTTP server.
>
> Works fine with Express.

You only need to use nginx or any orther proxy solution (there are nodejs modules too you could integrate with your application) if you want serve each virtualhost with different applications (because they cannot listen to the same port).